# Load user defined op with relative path in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

How to load a user defined op with relative path in tensorflow? It works fine with absolute path. But I want to do it using relative path.

I used this command to build the op:

```
bazel build -s --copt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" \
    -c opt //tensorflow/core/user_ops:zero_out.so
```

The build file I used is:

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_library")
tf_custom_op_library(
name = "zero_out.so",
srcs = ["zero_out.cc"],
)
```

The below code doesn't work. It shows image not found error. 
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: dlopen(zero_out.so, 6): image not found

```
import os.path
import tensorflow as tf
_zero_out_module = tf.load_op_library(os.path.join(tf.resource_loader.get_data_files_path(),'zero_out.so'))
zero_out = _zero_out_module.zero_out
```

But the below code does work properly.

```
import os.path
import tensorflow as tf
_zero_out_module = tf.load_op_library('/Users/sahilsingla/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/zero_out.so')
zero_out = _zero_out_module.zero_out
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative paths in bazel, for instance

```
cd tensorflow/core/user_ops
bazel build -s --copt=-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 :zero_out.so
```

or:

```
cd tensorflow/core
bazel build -s --copt=-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 user_ops:zero_out.so
```